# How to safely provide liquidity on Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, defi, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3

I created a token and wanted to provide a liquidity with all the tokens I have, but it seems like I need a lot of ethereum, does anyone know how to safely do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So It would be best to do three starting positions

first it's best to create a Full range position, this will help prevent errors with the pool being out of range

then You want to place the amount of ETH/WETH you want for LQ in a more narrow range that you think it will trade in. Let the UI choose token amount

then you can place the rest of your tokens within a single sided LQ position, just has to be on one side of the active / current price range

**keep in mind V3 does not support FOT, rebase or reflection tokens**